# Why my notification doesn't work?

Tags: android, notifications

I put here my code...
I explain my problem..
when I create a notification, it appears to me immediately even if I enter a specific time to make it appear. 
at that time instead opens automatically as if i push on notification. 
can you tell me how I can play it at the time that i inserted?

thanks

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class Allarm {

private Context context;

public Allarm(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void createAlarm(String rip,String title,String object,String dati) {


        String day= "01";
        String month= "01";
        String year= "2014";
        String hour= "00";
        String minute = "02";
String date = day+"/"+month+"/"+year+" "+hour+":"+minute; 

        Calendar myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        myAlarmDate.set(Integer.valueOf(year), Integer.valueOf(month),
                Integer.valueOf(day), Integer.valueOf(hour),
                Integer.valueOf(minute), 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent =new Intent(context, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("dati", dati);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+date));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


  NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                .setWhen(myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis())
                .setContentText(object)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.avvio)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


                Notification notification=notificationBuilder.build();

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                notificationManager.notify((int) myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), notification);

    }




}
```

Comment: plz explain it briefly?

Answer (score 2):

The method [`NotificationManager.notify(int id, Notification notification)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) posts the notification immediately. The first argument is an id you specify and not the time the notification should be displayed.

You could use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a notification.

Comment: thanks..how can i use alarmManager?
i've tried with no success